# Finding triangle’s area using Cartesian plane

Tags: geometry, triangles

[Question 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9ttD.jpg)

Hi,

I am a high school student and I've been trying to solve the problem shown in the image for an hour or so now. The question requires me to basically find the area of triangle using the coordinates of straight lines. If helpful, the unit has been focusing on equations of straight lines. I would really appreciate some guidance on how I might tackle this question.

Comment: The lines are perpendicular. You know essentially the slope of one line (two points are given) and thus you can find the other slope. With that, both equations of the lines can be found. And thus x-intercepts are easy to obtain.

Comment: Hint: Find the area of the big triangle, and the area of the white non-shaded part (which is also a right triangle), and subtract them.

Comment: Can you figure out these five points  $(?,?)$ where line 1 crosses the x axis; $(-3,12)$ where the two lines interest; $(?,?)$ where line 2 crosses the y-axix;  $(0,0)$ the origin, and $(?,?)$ where line 2 crosses the x-axis.  Can you figure out what those five points are? Can you use them to figure the areas of the big triangle and the small triangle are.

Comment: Yes I can figure out the five points however I don't know how to figure out the length between them. For example, what would the length between (-3, 12) and (6, 0) be?

Comment: distance formula $d = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}$

Comment: Oh thank you very much Dhanvi! I think I might give it another shot.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R^2}$, if two lines are perpendicular, and neither line is horizontal (i.e. slope of zero), then the slope of the second line is the negative reciprocal of the slope of the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slope of the line $L$ thru $A=(-3,12)$ and $B=(6,0)$ is $S=\frac {12-0} {(-3)-6}=-4/3.$ So the slope of the line $M, $ perpendicular to $L$ and passing thru $A,$ has slope $\frac {-1}{S}=3/4.$

$M$ meets the $x$-axis at the un-labelled point that I will call $C.$

As you travel  from $C$ to $A$ along $M,$ your $y$-coordinate's change, which is $12,$ is $3/4$ of your $x$-co-ordinate change because $M$'s slope is $3/4.$ So the $x$-co-ordinate change from $C$ to $A$ is $\frac{12}{3/4}=16.$ So $C=((-3)-16,0)=(-19,0).$

So in $\triangle ABC$ the length of the base $AC$ is $6-(-19)=25.$ And the height of the point $B$ above $AC$  is $12.$ So the area of $ABC$ is $(25)(12)/2=150.$

Now  $\triangle A'B'C',$ with $A'=(0,0), B'=B=(6,0),$ and with $C'$ being the intersection of $AB$ with the $y$-axis, is similar to $\triangle ABC,$ as they have equal sets of interior angles. We have length $A'B'=6.$  We have length $AB=\sqrt {(6-(-3))^2+(0-12)^2}=\sqrt {3^2} \sqrt {3^2+4^2}=15.$

So $A'B'/AB=6/15.$

So the area of $A'B'C'$ is $(6/15)^2$ times the area of $ABC.$ That is, the area of $A'B'C'$ is $(6/15)^2\cdot 150 =(4/25)\cdot 150=24.$

So the shaded area  is $150-24=126.$

Comment: If two lines are $\perp$ to each other and if neither one is parallel to nor equal to either of the co-ordinate axes, then the product of the slopes of those two lines is $-1$.